# "Липкий блок" - свой элементарный JQuery кусочек кода.

Tags: jquery, javascript

**Требуется** сделать "липкий блок" - блок, прикрепленный к верху страницы. Прокрутка на него не влияет, он всегда по верху. Липким он должен становиться, если страница прокрученна вниз на 107 и более пикселей :).

**Мой подход** таков:

1. Создать css-класс, реализующий липкость: фиксированное позиционирование и т.д.
2. Создать JS-ку (JQuery используется), определяющую уровень прокрученности страницы. Если больше 107px - добавлять класс. Меньше - снимать.

С первым проблем нету, все ок, а вот в JS/JQuery слаб. Набросал базовую версию.

**Покритикуйте, пожалуйста :)**

```
<script>
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        var scrolled = $(this).scrollTop();
        if( scrolled >= 107 ) {
            $('#stiky-block').addClass('sticked');
        }   
        if( scrolled <= 107 ) {     
            $('#stiky-block').removeClass('sticked');
        }
    });
</script>
```

**Получается**, что этот код отрабатывает каждый разкогда пользователь прокручивает страницу. Следовательно, каждый раз по всей странице ищется объект #sticky-block. Может есть смысл сохранить его в отдельную переменную перед началом работы скрипта?

**Получается**, что каждый раз при прокрутке, например от 500px до 600px и от 600px до 700px #sticky-block`у прилепляется класс. По идее алгоритм должен работать только один раз, если перешли границу в 107px и наоборот. Может сюда стоит добавить флаги?

Чуть более логичный вариант:

```
<script>
   $(window).scroll(function(){
        var scrolled = $(this).scrollTop();
        if( scrolled >= 107 && ! $('#sticky-block').hasClass('sticked') ) {
            $('#sticky-block').addClass('sticked');
        }    
        if( scrolled <= 107 && $('#sticky-block').hasClass('sticked')) {        
            $('#sticky-block').removeClass('sticked');
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Все тут верно. Ваша оптимизация лишняя. Все и так будет хорошо.  
[Туториал Fixed Floating Elements](http://jqueryfordesigners.com/fixed-floating-elements/)

Comment: Спасибо, попробую вникнуть :)

Comment: В статье делается то же самое, только автор использует не конкретные 107, а вычисляет это значение.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не очень понял в чем проблема. Объект по идентификатору ищется быстро.
Втрое. Добавьте условий просто. Проверяйте наличие класса (.hasClass('')), чтобы не присваивать 100 раз.
Добавьте условия на границу.

Вы это сами описали :) Так что вперед

Comment: Да, точно, hasClass! http://jsfiddle.net/RMKFp/1/ Так логичнее :)
Что вы имеет ввиду под границами?

Comment: Насчет границ я немного не то понял. Забудьте :)