# Увеличение блока при прокрутке

Tags: jquery, html, вконтакте

Здравствуйте! Подскажите как работает такая вещь. При прокрутке страницы до определенного момента блок увеличивается. Такая вещь Имеется Вконтакте при прокрутке стены. Если есть у кого нибудь пример подкиньте пожалуйста! Или идею как можно реализовать. Чем воспользоваться. Заранее Спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Я задавал подобный вопрос недавно: [Липкий блок](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/147076/js-%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-jquery-%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BA-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0). В вашем случае, вместо класса добавляющего липкость будет класс меняющий ширину.

Comment: Обратите, кстати, внимание на то, что если у вас резиновый макет, то высота может менятся не только при скроллинге, но и при сужении окна. По этому функцию в моем примере надо вызывать не только при скроллинге, но и при ресайзинге. По этому поводу я тоже задавал вопрос :)
http://hashcode.ru/questions/147770/jquery-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D0%BE-resize-%D0%B8-scroll